# illegal argument exception , No View Found for the class fragment

Tags: view, android-tabs, fragment-backstack

Hi have Menu Drawer in My Main Activity and have 2 Fragment , first Fragment Contain tab bar and second fragment is simple. second fragment simple fragment.

when i am on Second fragment and on back stack back press button i pop last fragment at that time it will give me error illegal argument exception.

here is main class(Menu Drawer):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private SessionCreator m_session;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private static String[] mPlanetTitles = {"NewsFeed","Profile", "Worlds", "Leaderboard", 
                                    "Map", "Feedback", "Settings"};

boolean btn_back = true;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);



    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    //mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.drawer_menu,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()


        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
          // getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(2);
    }

    Common.setObject(mDrawerLayout, mDrawerList);



    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
            if(f!=null){

                updateTitelandDrawer(f);
            }
        }

        private void updateTitelandDrawer(Fragment f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String fragclassName = f.getClass().getName();
            Log.d("CheckFragmentStatus", ""+f.toString());


        }
    });


}


/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    //menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args;

    AppData mApp = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
    String szUserId = mApp.getUserId();


    switch (position) {
    case 0:// news feed
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        fragment = new NewsfeedActivity();
        args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("userId", szUserId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        break;

    case 1:// profile

        fragment = new ProfileDetailsActivity();
        args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("userId", szUserId);
        args.putString("profileId", szUserId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        break;

    case 2:// world
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
        fragment = new WorldsMainActivity();
        args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        break;


    default:
        getActionBar()
                .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
    }

    // call fragment class
    replaceFragment(fragment);

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coming_soon, container, false);
         int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
         String planet = mPlanetTitles[i];
         getActivity().setTitle(planet);
         return rootView;
    }
}



private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
      String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
      String fragmentTag = backStateName;

      FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
      boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

      if (!fragmentPopped) { 
          transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
      } 
      transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
      transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
      transaction.commit(); 
      } 



// handle fragment navigation backstack push/pop operation 
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        Log.d("MyHomeBackStack", ""
                + getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());

        if (btn_back) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btn_back = false;
        } else {
            Exitdialog_message("Do you want to exit?");
        }
    } else {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}


//application exit dialog box 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void Exitdialog_message(String string) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            HomeActivity.this).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    alertDialog.setMessage(string);

    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
  }

 }
```

here is my fragment class 1.

```
 public class NewsfeedActivity extends Fragment {



// Declaring our tabs and the corresponding fragments.
ActionBar.Tab ownNF, groupNF, publicNF;
Fragment ownFragment = new NewsFeedOwn();
Fragment groupFragment = new NewsFeedGroups();
Fragment publicFragment = new NewsFeedPublic();
ActionBar actionBar;

SessionCreator session;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_main, container,false);



    return myInflatedView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    // Asking for the default ActionBar element that our platform supports.
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

    // Screen handling while hiding ActionBar icon.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Screen handling while hiding Actionbar title.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    actionBar.removeAllTabs();
    // Creating ActionBar tabs.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    // Setting custom tab icons.

     ownNF = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.nf_own_blue);
     groupNF = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.nf_group_blue);
     publicNF = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.nf_public_blue);

    ((NewsFeedOwn)ownFragment).setParentFrag(getActivity());
    ((NewsFeedOwn)ownFragment).setFrag(this);

    ((NewsFeedGroups)groupFragment).setParentFrag(getActivity());
    ((NewsFeedGroups)groupFragment).setFrag(this);

    ((NewsFeedPublic)publicFragment).setParentFrag(getActivity());
    ((NewsFeedPublic)publicFragment).setFrag(this);

    // Setting tab listeners.
    ownNF.setTabListener(new NewsfeedTabListener(ownFragment));
    groupNF.setTabListener(new NewsfeedTabListener(groupFragment));
    publicNF.setTabListener(new NewsfeedTabListener(publicFragment));

    // Adding tabs to the ActionBar.
    actionBar.addTab(ownNF);
    actionBar.addTab(groupNF);
    actionBar.addTab(publicNF);

}

public String getUserId()
{
    // get user id and profile id
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    String szUserId = data.getString("userId");
    return szUserId;
}

public void executeGetNewsFeedTask(int nsType, NewsFeedFragment frag)
{
    GetNewsFeedTask trickCmd = new GetNewsFeedTask(nsType, frag);
    trickCmd.execute();
}




@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //getActivity().getActionBar().removeAllTabs();
//      getActivity().getActionBar().removeAllTabs();
//      getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

//      Fragment mFrag = new NewsfeedActivity();
//      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFrag).commit();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

}

here is second fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                    ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("ProfileBackStackAction", ""+getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());

    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>1){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
 //         getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 //         getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 //         getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    }else{
        getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    }




    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_details_main, container,false);
    init(myInflatedView);


    m_bAllTricksView = false;

    // get user id and profile id
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    szUserId = data.getString("userId");
    szProfileId = data.getString("profileId");


    m_lvTricks = (ListView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.lvLatestTricks);
    adapter = new FollowerListAdapter(getActivity(), trickList);
    m_lvTricks.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_lvTricks.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            FollowerOrTrickItem trickItem = (FollowerOrTrickItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrickDetailsActivity.class);
            //TODO:: pass trick id, profile id, user id
            intent.putExtra("userId", szUserId);
            intent.putExtra("profileId", szProfileId);
            intent.putExtra("trickId", trickItem.szProfileId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    m_civProfPic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("userId", szUserId);
            bundle.putString("profileId", szProfileId);             
            bundle.putString("ImagePath", ImageUrl);
            UpdatePicture updatePicture = new UpdatePicture();
            updatePicture.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction transection = manager.beginTransaction();
            transection.replace(R.id.content_frame, updatePicture);
            transection.addToBackStack("updatePicture");
            transection.commit();


        }
    });

    m_ivCover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("userId", szUserId);
            bundle.putString("profileId", szProfileId);
            bundle.putString("ImagePath", CoverImageUrl);
            UpdatePicture updateCover = new UpdatePicture();
            updateCover.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction transection = manager.beginTransaction();
            transection.replace(R.id.content_frame, updateCover);
            transection.addToBackStack("updateCover");
            transection.commit();
        }
    });

    // send request to fetch worlds and fetch status of each three levels from response
    String strURL = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=getProfileData";
    ProfileCmdTask taskCmd = new ProfileCmdTask();
    taskCmd.execute(szUserId, szProfileId, strURL);



    return myInflatedView;
}
```

here is my log cat when i will back from second fragment to first fragment with tab bar is show blank page or listview and when i try to move second tab it will give me illegal  Argument exception problem

here is my log:

```
 06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020): Process: com.prostart.zoneln, PID: 4020
 06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0072 (com.prostart.zoneln:id/newsfeed_root) for fragment NewsFeedGroups{530daf0c #2 id=0x7f0b0072}
    06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
     06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
   06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
  06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
  06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
  06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    06-18 02:19:03.004: E/AndroidRuntime(4020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this link is show how my backstack work

http://pastebin.com/sKXRvSpT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

> popBackStack

instead of

> popBackStackImmediate